# Why I cannot compile ARM BE8 ELF using GCC?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, arm, cross-compiling, endianness

Iv'e been trying to compile the following code for an ARM BE8 system (running little-endian code with big-endian data access).

My code looks as follows:

```
.global main
.type main, %function

main:
    ldr pc, =0x12345678
```

The expected output is:

```
04 f0 1f e5 <- little endian opcode
12 34 56 78 <- big endian data
```

I'm using a Makefile, first trying to compile using:

`arm-unknown-linux-musleabi-gcc main.S -o main.o -mbig-endian -mbe8`

Then, linking using:

`arm-unknown-linux-musleabi-ld main.o -o main -mbig-endian`

but output binary `main` contains big-endian code instead of little.

When trying to link using:

`arm-unknown-linux-musleabi-ld main.o -o main -mbig-endian -mbe8`

I'm receiving the following error:

`... is already in final BE8 format`

Comment: the older arm cores do not support be8, only the newer ones, so try specifying an armv7 architecture.  see if that changes it and/or determine what default core you are set for in this gnu binary

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e found the problem!

When posting the question, I tried to simplify the build lines from my original `Makefile`. The actual problem was trying to run `ld` for several times (for generating multiple types for my final ELF).

It seems that `-mbe8` cannot operate on an existing ELF file with the `-be8` attribute (re-linking).

The solution as to transfer this flag to only the final `ld` command.